# xpath query returning wrong values when using greater and less than?

Tags: xml, xpath

This query is returning values less than 1000. It should only be returning values between 1000 and 1100. Why is that?

`//results/Building[ 1 = 1  and (( Vacancy/sqft > 1000 ) and ( Vacancy/sqft < 1100 ) ) ]`

The query will return the following building, which has vacancies less than 1000 square feet and greater than 1100 square feet:

```
<Building>
  <Vacancy><sqft>900</sqft></Vacancy>
  <Vacancy><sqft>1000</sqft></Vacancy>
  <Vacancy><sqft>2000</sqft></Vacancy>
  <Vacancy><sqft>500</sqft></Vacancy>
</Building>
```

Why is it included in the results?

Sample data:

```
<results>
  <Building><!--Shouldn't be selected.--></Building>

  <Building><!--Should be selected-->
    <Vacancy><sqft>1050</sqft></Vacancy>
  </Building>

  <Building><!--Should be selected-->
    <Vacancy><sqft>1025</sqft></Vacancy>
    <Vacancy><sqft>1075</sqft></Vacancy>
  </Building>

  <Building><!--Shouldn't be selected-->
    <Vacancy><sqft>10</sqft></Vacancy>
    <Vacancy><sqft>50</sqft></Vacancy>
  </Building>

  <Building><!--Should be selected.-->
    <Vacancy><sqft>1050</sqft></Vacancy>
    <Vacancy><sqft>2000</sqft></Vacancy>
  </Building>

  <Building><!--Should be selected.-->
    <Vacancy><sqft>900</sqft></Vacancy>
    <Vacancy><sqft>1040</sqft></Vacancy>
  </Building>

  <Building><!--Shouldn't be selected-->
    <Vacancy><sqft>10500</sqft></Vacancy>
  </Building>

  <Building><!--Shouldn't be selected-->
    <Vacancy><sqft>900</sqft></Vacancy>
    <Vacancy><sqft>1000</sqft></Vacancy>
    <Vacancy><sqft>2000</sqft></Vacancy>
    <Vacancy><sqft>500</sqft></Vacancy>
  </Building>

</results>
```

Thanks.

Comment: So you're saying it's returning the Building node above?  Also why is are your conditions structured the way they are (`1=1` and extra parens)?  I noticed that `results` is missing from your XML structure, was that just a typo or does the XML you are dealing with not have a `results` node?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to add <results>. 1=1 is there because I am adding other additional criteria on the fly.

Comment: I'm using objective-c, libxml.

Comment: What tools/programming language are you using? And what should it return?

Comment: Why should your empty building node be selected?  It doesn't have any vacancies let alone any vacancies between 1000 and 1100.

Comment: @Simone: In english, what buildings do you want to select? For example, "All buildings with a vacancy between 1000 and 1100 square feet", "All buildings with vacancies, where all vacancies are between 1000 and 1100 square feet".

Comment: @Simone: another thing that will help us is if you edit your question and change the Building comments asking if they should be selected to a statement as to whether or not they should be selected (i.e. change "Should this be selected?" to "Should be selected" or "Shouldn't be selected").

Comment: @Simone, take a look at my update and let me know if that's what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, both records up above should be selected, in English, "All buildings with a vacancy between 1000 and 1100 square feet" . Thanks for all your help.  I think someone posted what I am looking for.

Comment: @Simone: Good question, +1. See my answer for two short and correct XPath expressions that select, respectively, all "should" nodes and all "should" + "should it?" nodes. :)

Comment: @Simone: three elements are of uncertain inclusion (don't neglect the building with no vacancies). Under the question you should see an "edit" link, which you can use to update the comments on those nodes and remove the ambiguity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you also need to match buildings with some sqft outside your criteria but at least one sqft between 1000-1100 like this

```
  <Building>Should this be selected too?
    <Vacancy><sqft>1000</sqft></Vacancy>
    <Vacancy><sqft>1050</sqft></Vacancy>
    <Vacancy><sqft>2000</sqft></Vacancy>
  </Building>
```

If yes, then use XPath expression

```
/results/Building[Vacancy/sqft[. > 1000 and 1100 > . ] or not(Vacancy)]
```

It also selects buildings with no `<Vacancy>` element (as requested).

Answer (score 8):

The sample Building has a Vacancy child with sqft of 2000, so `Vacancy/sqft > 1000` succeeds. It has a child with sqft of 1000 (and 900 and 500), so `Vacancy/sqft < 1100` succeeds. Thus the xpath selects the Building.

The comparison expressions (such as `Vacancy/sqft <= 1000`) are implicitly qualified with "[there exists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification)"–as in "there exists a Vacancy child that has a sqft child with value > 1000"–because `Vacancy/sqft` is a [set of nodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-sets), rather than a single node. Moreover, each comparison has its own qualification, so the sqft in `Vacancy/sqft > 1000` doesn't need to be the same sqft as in `Vacancy/sqft < 1100`. Note that `//results/Buildings` is a node set; the predicate `[...]` applies separately to each item in the set, which is why there isn't an issue with qualifiers. Translating your original xpath into English, we get:

> Select the buildings (in the results) such that 1=1 and there exists a vacancy square footage > 1000 and there exists a vacancy square footage < 1100.

Let's take the English statement of the desired query and make it a little closer to a statement of logic, arriving at one of:

> Select the buildings (in the results) such that there exists a vacancy with square footage such that it's > 1000 and it's < 1100
>
> Select the buildings (in the results) such that there exists a vacancy such that the square footage > 1000 and the square footage < 1100

The former leads to jasso's solution, the latter to:

`//results/Building[ Vacancy[1000 < sqft and sqft < 1100] ]`

### Original solution

(Note: this answered the original question, when it wasn't clear what the OP wanted. The technique may prove useful to others with a similar problem but different requirements, so I'm leaving it in.)

Try the logical double-negation of the condition:

`//results/Building[ Vacancy and not (Vacancy/sqft <= 1000 or Vacancy/sqft >= 1100) ]`

This predicate includes a test for Vacancy children to filter out cases that are otherwise trivially true, i.e. buildings with no vacancies. The English equivalent of this solution is:

> Select buildings (in the results) such that the building has a vacancy and it's not the case that there exists a vacancy square footage <= 1000 or there exists a vacancy square footage >= 1100

In fewer words:

> Select all buildings with vacancies where no vacancy has <= 1000 square feet or >= 1100 square feet.

In fewer words still:

> Select all buildings with vacancies where all vacancies are between 1000 and 1100 square feet.

Comment: Yes I see your logic but that's not the result I was expecting.

Comment: What outis is saying is that all of the conditions in your predicate are met, so you will get that `Building` every time. You need to look at it from the context of the `Building`. You're not testing all of the `Vacancy/sqft` values at once. It's easier to think of the XPath you wrote like this: Does 1 = 1? Yes. Does `Building` have a `Vacancy/sqft` greater than 1000? Yes. Does `Building` have a `Vacancy/sqft` less than 1100? Yes.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> //results
>   /Building[1 = 1 and 
>             (( Vacancy/sqft > 1000 ) and (Vacancy/sqft < 1100 ))]
> ```
>
> This query is returning values less
>   than 1000. It should only be returning
>   values between 1000 and 1100. Why is
>   that?

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans

> If one object to be compared is a
>   node-set and the other is a number,
>   then the comparison will be true if
>   and only if there is a node in the
>   node-set such that the result of
>   performing the comparison on the
>   number to be compared and on the
>   result of converting the string-value
>   of that node to a number using the
>   number function is true.

Node set comparisons are **existencial comparisons**. `Vacancy/sqft > 1000` means: *Is there at least one `Vacancy/sqft` greater than 1000?*

If you want to select `Building` elements having `Vacancy/sqft` grand children, and all of them in the range (1000,1100), this XPath expression:

```
/results/Building[Vacancy/sqft and not(Vacancy/sqft[1000 >= . or . >= 1100])]
```

Comment: This expression doesn't match "All buildings with a vacancy between 1000 and 1100 square feet". But maybe the OP added that definition after you posted your answer. +1 for explanation of key concept, existential comparisons.

Comment: @LarsH: all the answers were given before the English statement of the query was specified, so there's that. We all headed off in different directions before the goal was set.

Comment: @outis: HIWTH (hate it when that happens)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your xpath to this:

```
//results/Building[number(Vacancy/sqft) > 1000  and  number(Vacancy/sqft) < 1100 ]
```

I suspect it's treating your `Vacancy/sqft` node like text which could be causing some weirdness...

I removed your 1=1 and extra parens because I didn't see a need for them.  The main point is to try the `number` function.

**UPDATE**

This one is a little odd but it grabs the ones you want plus the one you aren't sure if you want (`Should this be selected?`):

```
//results/Building[count(Vacancy[sqft > 1000  and  sqft < 1100 ]) = count(Vacancy)]
```

and if you want to exclude that one:

```
//results/Building[(count(Vacancy[sqft > 1000  and  sqft < 1100 ]) = count(Vacancy)) and count(Vacancy) > 0]
```

Also I am using [this site](http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm) to text my xpaths, if there is some sort of fundamental difference between how they do it and how objective-c does let me know...

Comment: Good catch, but "If one object to be compared is a node-set and the other is a number, then the comparison will be true if and only if there is a node in the node-set such that the result of performing the comparison on the number to be compared and on the result of converting the string-value of that node to a number using the number function is true." (XPath 1.0, §3.4).

Comment: Also, that was one of the most complicated sentences I've ever read.  Is it just me?

Comment: This fails with this data: `<Building><Vacancy><sqft>1050</sqft></Vacancy><Vacancy><sqft>1101</sqft></Vacancy></Building>` (it will return this `Building` even though there is a `Vacancy/sqft` greater than 1100.

Comment: There is also one between 1000 and 1100.  I was under the impression that she wanted to return building nodes that had sqft in that range...

Comment: Yes, thanks, I tested it, but that doesn't make a difference. It already compares it as a number....

Comment: @Abe: Welcome to the world of standards documents. Sadly, they get much, much worse. Your solution does indeed work with my first test data, but try it against the updates. The problem is that number() is applied to an entire node set, which first converts the set to a single string.

Comment: @outis: There's nothing wrong with the standards document. `number()` works exactly as described. The problem is that people try to use functions and operators without understanding the distinction between those that operate on nodesets, and those that force their argument(s) to a single value. Thus @Abe's first XPath tests the first `Vacancy/sqft` in each building, but ignores the others.

Comment: @Abe, re: your last couple of XPath expressions -- `count(A[test]) = count(A)` is saying "all `A` satisfy `test`", i.e. "there are no `A` that don't satisfy `test`". That can be written `not(A[not(test)])`. This will likely be more efficient since it doesn't have to count the number of A's.

Comment: @LarsH: I didn't say the standards document was in error, merely that standards document language is complex. For the rest, we're saying the same thing: it's a problem of application, rather than specification. `number()`, when applied to a node set, won't accomplish what Abe wanted it to accomplish.

Comment: @outis, I agree that standards documents are sometimes difficult to understand, but then their role is not that of a tutorial for the unacquainted. Their role is that of a precise specification for implementors, trainers, and those that must know the language inside and out. I didn't learn XPath primarily from the standards doc, and I wouldn't expect Abe to either.

Comment: @Larsh: definitely. They're also helpful when something doesn't work the way we expect it, which means something is wrong with our conceptual model. A standards doc tells us how things should behave, so that we can adjust and correct said conceptual model.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two XPath expressions:

**1. The following selects all nodes that you believe *should* be selected**:

```
/*/*[Vacancy and not(Vacancy[. < 1000 or . > 1100])]
```

1. **The following selects all nodes that you believe should be selected and all those you are not certain about. It *doesn't* select any node that you are certain should not be selected**:

`/*/*[not(Vacancy) or Vacancy[. > 1000 and not(. > 1100)]]`

**This XSLT transformation can be used to verifu the correctness of the XPath expressions**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
  "/*/*[Vacancy and not(Vacancy[. &lt; 1000 or . > 1100])]
  "/>

===============================
  <xsl:copy-of select=
  "/*/*[not(Vacancy) or Vacancy[. > 1000 and not(. > 1100)]]
  "/>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<results>
  <Building><!--Should this be selected?--></Building>

  <Building><!--Should be selected-->
    <Vacancy><sqft>1050</sqft></Vacancy>
  </Building>

  <Building><!--Should be selected-->
    <Vacancy><sqft>1025</sqft></Vacancy>
    <Vacancy><sqft>1075</sqft></Vacancy>
  </Building>

  <Building><!--Shouldn't be selected-->
    <Vacancy><sqft>10</sqft></Vacancy>
    <Vacancy><sqft>50</sqft></Vacancy>
  </Building>

  <Building><!--Should this be selected?-->
    <Vacancy><sqft>1050</sqft></Vacancy>
    <Vacancy><sqft>2000</sqft></Vacancy>
  </Building>

  <Building><!--Should this be selected?-->
    <Vacancy><sqft>900</sqft></Vacancy>
    <Vacancy><sqft>1040</sqft></Vacancy>
  </Building>

  <Building><!--Shouldn't be selected-->
    <Vacancy><sqft>10500</sqft></Vacancy>
  </Building>

  <Building><!--Shouldn't be selected-->
    <Vacancy><sqft>900</sqft></Vacancy>
    <Vacancy><sqft>1000</sqft></Vacancy>
    <Vacancy><sqft>2000</sqft></Vacancy>
    <Vacancy><sqft>500</sqft></Vacancy>
  </Building>

</results>
```

**the wanted, correct results are produced**:

```
<Building><!--Should be selected-->
   <Vacancy>
      <sqft>1050</sqft>
   </Vacancy>
</Building>
<Building><!--Should be selected-->
   <Vacancy>
      <sqft>1025</sqft>
   </Vacancy>
   <Vacancy>
      <sqft>1075</sqft>
   </Vacancy>
</Building>

===============================
  <Building><!--Should this be selected?--></Building>
<Building><!--Should be selected-->
   <Vacancy>
      <sqft>1050</sqft>
   </Vacancy>
</Building>
<Building><!--Should be selected-->
   <Vacancy>
      <sqft>1025</sqft>
   </Vacancy>
   <Vacancy>
      <sqft>1075</sqft>
   </Vacancy>
</Building>
<Building><!--Should this be selected?-->
   <Vacancy>
      <sqft>1050</sqft>
   </Vacancy>
   <Vacancy>
      <sqft>2000</sqft>
   </Vacancy>
</Building>
<Building><!--Should this be selected?-->
   <Vacancy>
      <sqft>900</sqft>
   </Vacancy>
   <Vacancy>
      <sqft>1040</sqft>
   </Vacancy>
</Building>
```

Comment: I don't think either of these exactly matches "All buildings with a vacancy between 1000 and 1100 square feet"... or else I'm missing something.

Comment: @LarsH: One selects all "should" nodes, the other selects these + all "in doubt nodes".